# mod_rewrite .htaccess matches files only, need directory match too

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to re-write all traffic to an old_site folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+) old_site/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Works fine for

```
/blog/profile/index.php OR /blog/posts.php
```

But why doesn't it match

```
/blog/login/ or /blog/login
```

Do I need to specify a separate rule to handle directories with and without trailing slash/ ?

EDIT:

As per slugonamission I've added the -d directive

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) old_site/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

It's works for /blog/login/ however not for /blog/login , somehow without the trailing slash, it's not thought of as a directory? Is there a way to modify the current rule or do I need a new one to add the slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more research the following pattern matches what I need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)(/|)$ old_site/$1/$2/ [NC,QSA,L]
```

/blog/profile/index.php 
/blog/posts.php

Including directories with and without trailing slashes:

/blog/login/
/blog/login

Comment: Nice idea, the regexp `(/|)` I've never thought this way (it's usually `(/)?` or `(/){0,1}`

Answer (score 2):

You almost did it!
Here's what should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ old_site/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ old_site/$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Please tell me if it worked

:)

By the way, here's my favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choosek ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: got internal server errors, but it sent me in the right direction

Comment: the regex tool is awesome, been looking for something like that!

Comment: i've added the solution in the answers

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You also need to handle directories separately, which is done with the `-d` condition.

Comment: I guess adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` above the rewrite rule isn't the answer here...

Comment: I'm not sure if `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is the correct var to use here, as it should match the script requested (and I'm not sure what that will do when no actual script is specified). How about changing that to `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%2`?